# server and client sockets on android

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

I have a Client socket running on my Android application to send files to the Server socket running on the PC, via Wi-Fi. Everything works fine to this point. I would also like to create another thread within the same android application that acts as a server to receive any files sent from the PC (which runs a client as a separate thread). Is this two way communication possible over java sockets within the same application?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible, what are your doubts?

Comment: Are you aware that a `Socket` holds a full duplex (TCP) connection? This means that you can both send and receive via a Socket. Use `Socket.getInputStream()` and `Socket.getOutputStream()`.